# When you cast Mythic Blessing of Fervor, can you emulate two different metamagic feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, metamagic, stacking, mythic-adventures

When you cast [Mythic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells/#Blessing_of_Fervor) [Blessing of Fervor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blessing-of-fervor/), you are allowed to choose two of the choices on the list.

- Increase its speed by 30 feet.
- Stand up as a swift action without provoking an attack of opportunity.
- Make one extra attack as part of a full attack action, using its highest base attack bonus.
- Gain a +2 bonus on attack rolls and a +2 dodge bonus to AC and Reflex saves.
- **Cast a single spell of 2nd level or lower as if it were an enlarged, extended, silent, or still spell.**

> Affected creatures can choose two of the spell’s bonuses each round rather than one.

As long as you choose different metamagic feats, could you choose the final option twice and say enlarge and extend a spell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

The Mythic benefit allows you to select "two of the spell's bonuses" but does not include language to allow for selecting the same bonus twice. You couldn't use it to cast an *enlarged extended entanglement* nor could you increase your attack rolls and Reflex Saves by +4.

Comment: The speed increase is not a good example because both would be enhancement bonuses to speed and would not stack anyways. The metamagic feats however are a different case. You say it doesnt include language to allow for selecting the same choice twice, but it also doesnt say you cant.

Comment: It doesn't specify Enhancement bonus to speed; that seems to be untyped. I did change it to be the hit/Reflex in case that increases clarity. I don't agree that it not saying you can't is justification for selecting one thing twice. There are plenty of things the rules don't explicitly state you can't do, but do imply them, that we abide by. You can always ask your GM if their interpretation is different, but this is the RAW ("can choose two of the spell’s bonuses" is pretty explicit).